# How i can check for to file extentions with if statement for FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

in the bellow code i am trying to cacth first the file extention before process the code and upload the file but what happen is when i do like that:

FileExtention == ".jpg || .png"
its move to else statement where the files that i choosed it are: .jpg. So please could you help me to make the code check and accept more than one extention as above .jpg || .png. As if i add one extention as below it will work fine but if i do as above it will not and it will move to else statement

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile || FileUpload2.HasFile || FileUpload3.HasFile || FileUpload4.HasFile || FileUpload5.HasFile)
{
    if (FileExtention == ".jpg" || FileExtention2 == ".jpg" || FileExtention3 == ".jpg" || FileExtention4 == ".jpg" || FileExtention5 == ".jpg")
    {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all your file extensions in one array, all your valid extensions in other and check with linq (lowercase before):

```
var files = new [] { FileExtention, FileExtention2, FileExtention3, FileExtention4, FileExtention5 };
var extensions = new [] {".jpg", ".png"};
if (files.All(f => extensions.Contains(f.ToLower())))
{
   //...do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write `FileExtention == ".jpg || .png"` to test if `FileExtention == ".jpg"` or if `FileExtention == ".png"`. The reason is, that `".jpg || .png"` is a string, not an expression.

You can do that like this: `FileExtention == ".jpg" || FileExtention == ".png"`

Comment: Hi @Matyas  thanks for your reply, i have did as you mention but there is another problem that i tried to upload .docx file and the code accepted where it should only accept .jpg or .png??!

Comment: how do you obtain the value of `FileExtention`?